# I have two problems with my project.1) pass and getting string value from one activity to another 2) Listview in dialogue in OnPost Execute

Tags: android, database, listview, android-intent

I'm trying to do a simple database project on Android. I have two problems with my project:

1. I want to pass a string value from the first activity to the second activity
   and in both activities pass the string value to a third activity. I
   can't get the string values in the third activity. To check it I have a
   print sts, but it reported nothing. There are no errors thrown.
2. I want to display data in a listview inside a dialog in the second activity
       when `OnPostExecute` is triggered. I'm getting an error, but I'm doing it with just an
       `arrayadapter`. It displays successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

See my code [here](http://pastebin.com/KcVrUXaZ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a Value from Activity to Activty 
use Intent.putExtra before starting Activty 
Like This Below

```
`Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivty.class);
intent.putExtra("Key", "Value");
startActivity(intent);`
```

and on the next Activty Recive it using getExtra

```
 Bundle getValue= getIntent().getExtras();

 if(GetValue!=null);

 String GetIntentValue= GetValue.getExtras("Key");
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first class

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextclass.class);`

`intent = putExtra("YOUR_KEY" , yourstringhere);`

`startActivity(intent);`

On the receiving class

`Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();`

`if(data!=null);`

`String receiver = data.getExtras("YOUR_KEY");`

Goodluck.

Comment: In first activity value i get in second activity and both activity value i get in third activity..see my code. im correct..or what change i should do..